# Complex numbers in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

If we have two complex numbers, in polar form, as the numerator and denominator of a fraction, and we are asked to write them as a single complex number, is there an easier way to deal with them rather than the usual procedure? (By usual procedure I mean first expanding them by writing the value of each term and then realizing the denominator, etc.)

Thank you.

Comment: $z = r\cdot e^{i\varphi}$. $$\frac{z}{w} = \frac{r\cdot e^{i\varphi}}{\rho\cdot e^{i\psi}}.$$ Hmmmm.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ummm...... Completely lost you there.

Comment: It was meant to lead you to see that you can apply the functional equation of the exponential function for the argument(s), and that you can just divide the moduli.

Comment: I see. @DanielFischer So from there I can clearly see that I can multiply the moduli and just add the functional arguments if the two complex numbers are in multiplication?

Comment: Sure, $(r\cdot e^{i\varphi})(\rho \cdot e^{i\psi}) = (r\rho)\cdot e^{i\varphi}e^{i\psi}$.

Comment: kk thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you have $\frac{r_1 e^{i \theta_1}}{r_2 e^{i \theta_2}}$?  In that case you can divide them as you might expect to yield $\left(\frac{r_1}{r_2}\right) e^{i ( \theta_1 - \theta_2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\cis{\operatorname{cis}}$
If we have the fraction 
$$
\frac{r_{1}\cis(\theta_{1})}{r_{2}\cis(\theta_{2})}
$$

then in polar form this is the complex number 
$$
\frac{r_{1}}{r_{2}}\cis(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})
$$

It follows from the fact that $|\cis(\alpha)|=1$ hence $|r\cis(\alpha)|=r$
and from the trigonometric identities

Comment: To be clear, $cis(x) = e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$

Comment: @MJD - Thanks for the edit. I don't have the \cis command in Lyx but its on Math.SE (apparently)

Comment: I had to define it specially for your post, using `\def`.

Comment: Waittt..... So I can basically subtract the angles? (Extending from this, I suppose in multiplication I can add the angles?)

Comment: @Gummybears - Yes! You can use the notation of the exponent as others have if you wish - then you use the rules you already know (such as how to multiply them)

Comment: I have only learnt the polar form using $cos$ and $sin$ ??

Comment: @Gummybears $e^{i \theta}= \cos{\theta} + i \sin{\theta}$.